# Validate DateField data that depends on another DateField data in Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have recently starting to learn about Django.
I am trying to make a SearchForm that takes as inputs:

- location
- number of person
- arrival_date
- departure_date

I am hardly trying to make validations so that the arrival_date cannot be anterior to
`datetime.date.today()` and the departure_date cannot be anterior to  arrival_date. I managed to find [this in the Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) but I don't understand it properly. I tried both ways in the doc, but I must missing something because I get a `RunTimeError, super(): __class__ cell not found`.

It works fine to check the arrival date but I'm not sure it is the proper way.
Can someone please explain to me how I can use the resource linked here to make my form validations work as expected?

My POST requests:

```
location    'Paris'
nb_visitors '1'
arrival_date    '2020-07-30'
departure_date  '2020-07-29'
```

My Form (forms.py):

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from .validators import *

import datetime

class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    location = forms.CharField(
        label='Destination', 
        min_length=3,  
        max_length=40, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Paris'})
    )
    nb_visitors = forms.IntegerField(
        label='Nombres de Visiteurs', 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0, 'Le nombre de visiteurs ne peut être inférieur à 0.'),
            MaxValueValidator(15, 'Pour une visite agréable, un groupe peut être composé de 15 personnes maximum.')
        ],
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '1'})
    )
    arrival_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False, 
        validators=[check_arrival_date], 
        label='Date d\'arrivée', 
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'jj/mm/aaaa'})
    )
    departure_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False, 
        validators=[clean], 
        label='Date de départ', 
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'jj/mm/aaaa'})
    )
```

My Validation File (validators.py):

```py
from .forms import *

import datetime


def check_arrival_date(self):
    date  = self
    if date < datetime.date.today():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Nos visites ne peuvent être planifiées dans le passé.")

    return date

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    arrival_date = cleaned_data.get("arrival_date")
    departure_date = cleaned_data.get("departure_date")
    if departure_date.date() < arrival_date.date():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Vote date de départ doit être postérieure à votre d'arrivée")

    return arrival_date, departure_date
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to understand it myself.
I made a mistake using the `clean()` method as I would use my custom function `check_arrival_date()`.

I used the doc given in the first post :

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from .validators import *

import datetime

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.CharField(
        label='Destination', 
        min_length=3,  
        max_length=40, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Paris'})
    )
    nb_visitors = forms.IntegerField(
        label='Nombres de Visiteurs', 
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0, 'Le nombre de visiteurs ne peut être inférieur à 0.'),
            MaxValueValidator(15, 'Pour une visite agréable, un groupe peut être composé de 15 personnes maximum.')
        ],
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '1'})
    )
    arrival_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False,  
        label='Date d\'arrivée', 
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'jj/mm/aaaa'})
    )
    departure_date = forms.DateField(
        required=False, 
        label='Date de départ', 
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'placeholder':'jj/mm/aaaa'})
    )
    
        def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        logger.info(cleaned_data)

        if (cleaned_data.get("arrival_date") and not cleaned_data.get("departure_date")) or (not cleaned_data.get("arrival_date") and cleaned_data.get("departure_date")) :
            error_message = forms.ValidationError("Il faut spécifier les deux dates pour votre recherche.")
            self.add_error('arrival_date', error_message)

        elif cleaned_data.get("arrival_date") and cleaned_data.get("departure_date"):
            arrival_date = cleaned_data.get("arrival_date")
            departure_date = cleaned_data.get("departure_date")

            if arrival_date  < datetime.date.today():
                error_message = forms.ValidationError("Votre date d'arrivée dans la destination ne peut pas être antérieur à la date du jour.")
                self.add_error('arrival_date', error_message)

            elif arrival_date  >= datetime.date.today():
                if departure_date < arrival_date:
                    error_message = forms.ValidationError("Vote date de départ de la destination doit être postérieure à votre d'arrivée.")
                    self.add_error('departure_date', error_message)

        return cleaned_data
```